# Extract a matrix from a ListInterpolation

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, interpolation

I am looking to extract a large matrix from an InterpolatingFunction (roughly, 500x500x500), is there an easier way than extracting a `Table` ?

I want a matrix of the greyscale image data. Apologies for the lack of greyscale definition in the example I couldn't think how better to phrase it without attaching all my images. (my aim is to create a matrix of brain density from the greyscale data of scan slices.)

For example:

```
a = Import["ExampleData/CTengine.tiff", "Image3D"]
b = Image3DSlices[a];
c = Image3D[b, ColorFunction -> "Grayscale"];
d = ListInterpolation[ImageData[c]];

d[70, 70, 70]
```

> 0.133333

```
m =  ParallelTable[d[x, y, z], {x, 1, 10}, {y, 1, 10}, {z, 1, 10}]
```

Seems to be a hefty run time ( `AbsoluteTiming=25` for example above) , I'm sure there's a better way

Thanks

Comment: I think you need [`ArrayResample`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayResample.html).  For example, `ArrayResample[ImageData[c], {10, 10, 10}]` returns in less than a second on my machine.

Comment: @JasonB. Thanks! Perfect! Interesting function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ImageData[c]` is a 3-dimensional array with dimensions `{110, 256, 256}`.  To down-sample this to a `{30,30,30}` array, it's as easy as

```
ArrayResample[ImageData[c], {30, 30, 30}]
```

This is going to do the interpolation for you, but in a (hopefully) optimized way.